# Need help to search in an 2 dimensional array all diagonals

Tags: arrays, search

i have to read all diagonals of an 2 dimensional array. 
it should be dynamic so thats not matters what size the array has (no matter 2x2, 5x9....).

this is now my problem and i have no idea how to solve it.
is it possible to do this with loops?

thank you for your help :D

Comment: Post what you've tried so far. We aren't here to do the work for you, but rather help you with what you've tried.

Comment: thats the problem i have nothing so i cant post it^^
i thought about the problem and wrote it on sheets of paper but this doesnt help me-.-

Comment: Then show us what you have done on paper.

Comment: @user3328547 Start with understanding the problem, not thinking of a solution.  Work it out on paper.  I'm not quite sure how you'll find the diagonal of an nxm matrix/array where n =/= m.. that may be something to ask whoever assigned it to you

Comment: maybe is diagonal not the right word to describe what i mean but i do not now another description yet.
i write "Connect Four" and i need it to check whether someone won or not, so horizontal and vertical are easy but the rest is what i need. 
and i want programm the game dynamic so that i can say lets play on a 5 by 6 field or an 10 to 13 field or what ever so i need an algorithmn to check this. when i write it "static" i can programm each win-situations for the "diagonals" but it is not the sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your code is checking some coordinate (x,y) where x is the row number in your array and y is the column number like this:

```
array[x][y];
```

Note that this is a 90 degree inversion from a standard Cartesian coordinate grid. To access the cell to the upper left hand corner you need to lower both y and x so index your array like this:

```
array[x-1][y-1]
```

To access the upper right hand corner use:

```
array[x-1][y+1]
```

For the lower left corner:

```
array[x+1][y-1]
```

And for the lower right corner:

```
array[x+1][y+1]
```

To check a "diagonal" you need to pick which diagonal direction you want to check and just repeat checking like this until you either find four in a row or find the other player's piece or an empty space. It could be done with loops, however a more elegant solution would likely involve recursion.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. i will test it and look whether it works :)

Comment: @Rainbacon guess the question was is there a fstest way to search then looping over all the neighbor and if statements if x+1,y+1 etc is empty or full a little bit like this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729287/proper-and-efficient-way-to-find-the-geometric-lenght-of-a-single-pixel-curve