# Proper and efficient way to find the geometric lenght of a single pixel curve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, pixel

I have an image formed by curves one pixel wide (a single element in the corresponding `numpy` array).

The method I am using is to manually add the distances between pixels without overwriting starting from one end.

I would like a way to add these distances more efficiently. Thank you very much for taking the time to read this.

Sorry if my code is too long, that is partially why I know there must be a more efficient way.

The result in this example is => `dis = 2*sqrt(2) + 1`

```
import numpy as np

# Example image already loaded as a numpy array 
img = np.array(
    [[1,0,0],
     [0,1,0],
     [0,1,0],
     [0,0,1]])

# add a border of 0's to implement the logic I am using.

base = np.zeros([len(img_aux) + 2, len(img_aux[0]) + 2])
x = 0
for row in img_aux:
    y = 0
    for element in row:
        base[x + 1][y + 1] = 1 if element else 0
        y += 1
    x += 1

#    result

#    [[0,0,0,0,0]
#     [0,1,0,0,0],
#     [0,0,1,0,0],
#     [0,0,1,0,0],
#     [0,0,0,1,0]
#     [0,0,0,0,0]]

# build a base image where the pixels tell the amount of neighbors he has
# if i dont add the border this kind of operation will give me an exception

aux = base.copy()
for x in range(len(base)):
    for y in range(len(base[0])):
        if base[x][y] == 1:
            aux[x][y] = base[x - 1][y - 1] +
                        base[x - 1][y] +
                        base[x - 1][y + 1] +
                        base[x][y - 1] +
                        base[x + 1][y - 1] +
                        base[x + 1][y] +
                        base[x + 1][y + 1] +
                        base[x][y + 1]
        else:
            pass

#    result

#    [[0,0,0,0,0,0]
#     [0,1,0,0,0,0],
#     [0,0,2,0,0,0],
#     [0,0,2,0,0,0],
#     [0,0,0,1,0,0]
#     [0,0,0,0,0,0]]

# to make this shorter i asume that i have the coords of any "1" in the array
# asume this func find the coordinate in the pixel map of a random 1

x, y = coords(aux) 


# Here come the logic that find the distance
'''

if i start in the coords [1][1]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,X,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,2,0,0,0]
[0,0,2,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]

I find where is the next pixel whith a value diferent than 0 and sum the distance of the centroids of those 2 pixels, if the pixel are in horizontal or
vertical locations i sum 1 and if the other pixel is in a diagonal I sum sqrt(2)
the geometrical distance, after that I clean the pixel and find other until I have only one pixel left whitout any neighbors 


'''
end = 1
while end != 0:
    up = True if image[y - 1][x] != 0 else False
    up_right = True if image[y - 1][x + 1] != 0 else False
    right = True if image[y][x + 1] != 0 else False
    down_right = True if image[y + 1][x + 1] != 0 else False
    down = True if image[y + 1][x] != 0 else False
    down_left = True if image[y + 1][x - 1] != 0 else False
    left = True if image[y][x - 1] != 0 else False
    up_left = True if image[y - 1][x - 1] != 0 else False

    end = up + 
        up_right + 
        right + 
        down_right + 
        down + 
        down_left + 
        left + 
        up_left

    if end == 0:
        return dis
    else:
        if up:
            dis = dis + 1
            image[y][x] = 0
            y = y - 1

        if down:
            dis = dis + 1
            image[y][x] = 0
            y = y + 1

        if left:
            dis = dis + 1
            image[y][x] = 0
            x = x - 1

        if right:
            dis = dis + 1
            image[y][x] = 0
            x = x + 1

        if up_left:
            dis = dis + np.sqrt(2)
            image[y][x] = 0
            x = x - 1
            y = y - 1

        if up_right:
            dis = dis + np.sqrt(2)
            image[y][x] = 0
            x = x + 1
            y = y - 1

        if down_left:
            dis = dis + np.sqrt(2)
            image[y][x] = 0
            x = x - 1
            y = y + 1

        if down_right:
            dis = dis + np.sqrt(2)
            image[y][x] = 0
            x = x + 1
            y = y + 1

print(dis)
# this prints: 3.828...
# that is: 2*sqrt(2) + 1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'll just point out that `up = True if image[y - 1][x] != 0 else False` can be written just as `up = image[y - 1][x] != 0`.

Comment: So every pixel in the input is part of the same curve? If so, you could simplify your logic quite a bit if you realize that you can scan the image once, every two neighboring pixels that are set form a portion of the curve, add their distance to the running total. To avoid counting neighbors twice, check only half of the directions.

Comment: I have same question , my  code (last bit of https://stackoverflow.com/a/78006976/9877065 anwer) is like yours , was wondering if a fastest better approach exist